# Select rows with multiple filters in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a table with the following

```
| ServiceType | Email     |
| ----------  | --------- |
| 1           | a@abc.com |
| 2           | a@abc.com |
| 2           | a@abc.com |
| 2           | a@abc.com |
| 1           | b@abc.com |
| 1           | b@abc.com |
```

What I am trying to achieve is I need to filter the data based on the blow condition

if Service Type is different for the same email address we display the email according to the Service Type But if the serviceType is same for a email and having multiple records we show only one record.

eg: from the above table, we merge all a@abc.com for the Service type 2 and also we will show the Service type 1 for a@abc.com

Final query output should be

```
| ServiceType | Email     |
| ----------- | --------- |
| 1           | a@abc.com |
| 2           | a@abc.com |
| 1           | b@abc.com |
```

I tired with GROUPBY condition in SQL but I was not able to achieve this. can someone help me with this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried with DISTINCT?

Comment: @Arunkumar, are you really looking to select only two columns or there are other columns too in the select list?

Comment: @Pankaj I need to select the field ID also.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT`:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ServiceType, Email
FROM yourTable;
```

Or, use `GROUP BY`:

```sql
SELECT ServiceType, Email
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ServiceType, Email;
```

Note that `DISTINCT` is often implemented under the hood using `GROUP BY`.